# Map View Testing using UIAutomation javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode, ui-automation

I want to check whether my mapview is worked properly or not by changing the lat and long. I am using Automation javascript. Is there any code to change the lat and long in automation script. thanks in advance.`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/setLocation) this

```
UIATarget.localTarget().setLocation( { latitude:48.137222, longitude:11.575556 } );
```

should change the device's location.